# Does a ranged attack still have disadvantage if your target is adjacent to your large mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, mounted-combat

I am playing an artificer. My mechanical servant is a large creature. My question is if I am riding my mount (which is 10ft. by 10ft.) and I attack a creature adjacent to my mount with a ranged attack, does it have disadvantage or not?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7):

If *you* are within 5 feet it does, if you aren't it doesn't.

Being mounted does not [change your size](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928363566163308544) so your mount occupies a 10x10-foot space, you occupy a 5x5-foot space within your mount's space. If you are playing on a grid this has to be one of the 4 corner spaces of your mount's space - if so, the 5 of the 12 surrounding squares are within 5 feet and 7 aren't. If you don't play on a grid you could choose to be in the centre - if so all of the 12 surrounding squares are within 5 feet.

You can use your movement to change position on your mount but this may trigger Opportunity Attacks if you move out of an enemy's reach.

Comment: You don't occupy those spaces, you control those space sizes.